# R: Using aggregate within a function, not working

Tags: r, plot, aggregate

I am fairly new to R so apologies if an answer to this already exists that I am unable to find.

I cannot replicate the exact error I have with my own dataset, but since an error is produced nonetheless here we go. What I am trying to do is to create a function to calculate the average of several columns conditionnal on the values of other ones. Let's say that

```
d1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
d2 <- c(1:12)
d3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
df <- cbind(d1, d2, d3)

indicators_plotting1 <- function(a, b = d2, c = 1) {
  temp_data <- df %>%
    filter(d3 = c)
    for_plot <- aggregate(b ~ a, df, mean)
    plot(for_plot$b, for_plot$a)
}
indicators_plotting1(a = d1)
```

It works well if I do not include the `%>% filter(d3 = c)` bit. When I include it I get 
*Error in UseMethod("filter_") :   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"*.

That when I do it with the dataset I propose here. When I do it with my own larger one and with four filters, what I get is *Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'd1' not found*.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error messages seem pretty informative. It seems like filter doesn't work with a matrix. Maybe try making it a dataframe?

Comment: Per above, try replacing `cbind` with `data.frame` or `cbind.data.frame`.

Comment: Also, try avoiding different language constructs as you mix base R with tidyverse as latter has its own plotting and aggregation methods.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. Indeed, using ````data.frame```` solves the problem. Unfortunately, for my actual problem giving *Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'd1' not found* the issue is not solved. I will find a way to bring that here with something closer to my actual dataset. Noted regarding the language constructs, for the time being I mostly copypaste from stackoverflow or other places so I can understand I must be mixing things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider following base R adjustment using dynamic formula with `reformulate` in `aggregate()` and `plot()`. For below solution, you need to pass column reference as strings. And below works on named matrices or data frames:

```
indicators_plotting1 <- function(a, b = "d2", c = 1) {
  temp_data <- subset(df, d3 == c)
  for_plot <- aggregate(reformulate(a, b), temp_data, mean)
  plot(reformulate(b, a), for_plot)
}

indicators_plotting1(a = "d1")
```

Alternatively a one-line function:

```
indicators_plotting1 <- function(a, b = "d2", c = 1) {
  plot(reformulate(b, a), 
       aggregate(reformulate(a, b), subset(df, d3 == c), mean))
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/TGTX27095)</kbd> *(click `Run it (F8)` at bottom for plot)*

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: IT WORKS! AWESOME THANKS. I'll get to study how and why it does now :)