# R: Using smooth.spline within a function

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting

I am trying to create a smooth line using `smooth.spline` following advice from [Karsten W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480388/how-to-fit-a-smooth-curve-to-my-data-in-r). I have created a simple dataset which I call inside a function to draw plots. It has been aggregated following advice from [Parfait here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61213456/r-using-aggregate-within-a-function-not-working).

I am trying to get use `smooth.spline` to create a best fit for the points plotted, but for it to work I'd need it to call only the temporary dataset within the function, which I am unable to do.

Below a self-contained code :

```
d1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
d2 <- c(1:12)
d3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
df <- cbind(d1, d2, d3)
rm(d1, d2, d3)

average_plot <- function(a, b) {
  for_plot <- aggregate(reformulate(a, b), df, mean)
  smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(reformulate(a, b), spar=0.35)
  plot(reformulate(a, b), for_plot)
  lines(smoothingSpline)
}
average_plot("d1", "d3")
```

(I have to confess that I do not quite understand the `reformulate(a, b)` bit since, although it works, it is unlike the syntax shown in the manual.)

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Your linked answers use `d2` for the values on the x-axis, so actually you don't need to take `d3` into account. The `smooth.spline` function has no data argument, so we need to use `with`. It's better not to "hardcode" the data within a function, so we take up `dat` as another argument.

```
dat <- data.frame(d1=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), 
                 d2=1:12)

average_plot <- function(a, b, dat) {
  for_plot <- aggregate(reformulate(a, b), dat, mean)
  smoothingSpline <- with(for_plot, smooth.spline(reformulate(a, b), spar=0.35))
  plot(reformulate(a, b), for_plot)
  lines(smoothingSpline)
}
```

### Result

```
average_plot(a="d1", b="d2", dat)
```

[image]

Comment: That is great thanks. I am new to this and the use of ````with```` was also unclear to me so appreciated. I knew the 3rd variable was useless but thought it important to leave it there just to show I needed a function and not just a straight out plot :o... Otherwise, have you got a reference where I can better understand how ````reformulate()```` is used inside ````aggregate()````

Comment: It's no magic, just try `reformulate("d1", "d2")`. You can look up the help page for every R function using `?`, type e.g. `?reformulate` into your R console.